# How to pass variable created inside a function as pointer to another function

Tags: go

Hi Golang newbie here,

How to pass a variable as pointer argument to the another function.

```
func B(temp *?, event *Event) {
 temp["filla_a"] = event.Data["filla_a"]
 return temp
}

func A(event *Event) {
  temp := make(map[string]interface{})
  temp["po_id"] = event.Data["id"]
  temp = B(temp, event)
}
```

How to achive this in golang ?

Comment: As the elements of a map internal are pointers, I think a pointer to a map is a code smell.

Comment: I am not able to understand @apxp

Comment: A map holds a lot of pointers to values. You accessing the map via a key and you will get the value. So as internal the map uses pointers you don't need a pointer with a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it in `go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Event struct {
    Data map[string]string
}

func main() {
    e := new(Event)
    e.Data = make(map[string]string)
    e.Data["id"] = "THE_ID"
    e.Data["filla_a"] = "THE_FILLA_A"
    A(e)
}

func A(event *Event) {
    temp := make(map[string]interface{})
    temp["po_id"] = event.Data["id"]
    B(temp, event)
    fmt.Println(temp)
}

func B(temp map[string]interface{}, event *Event) map[string]interface{}{
    temp["filla_a"] = event.Data["filla_a"]
    return temp
}
```

I have assumed/made `event` as `struct` and declared the same in the program.

The `map` in `go` is a reference type (or better say it has pointer reference to internal data structures), so you do not need to pass a `pointer` of `map`, just pass/return the variable itself.

On the other hand `struct` (the Type of `e` in the `main()` function) is `value` type and need to be passed as a pointer to persist updates from called function.

**NOTE**: the `new` keyword creates a pointer to the type. Thus the `variable e` in the `main()` function is actually a pointer to the `Type Event`.

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Jbkm6z5a2Az

Hope it helps.